# Foreach Loop against a DateTime Object

Tags: php, datetime, for-loop, foreach, date-difference

I'am writing a small program that basically adds a fee to book if it is overdue just like a library.

So my thoughts are for each day that the book is late then there will be a fee added

IE: if the book is overdue for 5 days then the fee would be £10 = £2 a day.

Here is my code so far, not sure if it would be a "foreach" to be honest but i guess so

```
<?php
class Book
{

public $timeOverdue;

public function isBookOverdue()
{
    $returnedDate = new \DateTime('05/19/2015');
    $dueDate = new DateTime('05/08/2015');

    var_dump('returndDate', $returnedDate);
    var_dump('dueDate', $dueDate);

    if ($returnedDate > $dueDate) {

        echo 'Book is overdue.' . PHP_EOL;
        // $isBookOverdueStatus = true;
        $timeOverdue = date_diff( $returnedDate, $dueDate);
        echo $timeOverdue->format("%m month, %d days (total: %a days)") . PHP_EOL;
        var_dump($timeOverdue);

    } else {
        echo "Book is not overdue" .PHP_EOL. "Book has been returned" . PHP_EOL;
        die();
    }
}
}

$returnOfABook = new Book();
$returnOfABook->isBookOverdue();
$returnOfABook->addOverdueFee();
```

Then here is kind of what im thinking is possible? more sudo code than anything:

```
// public function addOverdueFee($timeOverdue)
// {
//   foreach ($timeOverdue as "day" => 1) {
//       // add fee
//   }
// }
```

and just for reference here is the date object that i want the loop to be running on:

```
object(DateInterval)#4 (15) {
["y"]=>
int(0)
["m"]=>
int(0)
["d"]=>
int(11)
["h"]=>
int(0)
["i"]=>
int(0)
["s"]=>
int(0)
["weekday"]=>
int(0)
["weekday_behavior"]=>
int(0)
["first_last_day_of"]=>
int(0)
["invert"]=>
int(1)
["days"]=>
int(11)
["special_type"]=>
int(0)
["special_amount"]=>
int(0)
["have_weekday_relative"]=>
int(0)
["have_special_relative"]=>
int(0)
}
```

So i thinkkkk that it would be something along the lines of this?

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Im still learning a lot so any tips, suggestions would be great, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the number of days the book is overdue and multiply it by 2. You already have everything you need as `timeOverdue` contains the number of days the book is overdue.

```
if ($returnedDate > $dueDate) {
    $timeOverdue = date_diff( $returnedDate, $dueDate);
    $amountToPay = $timeOverdue->days * 2;
}
```